# Linux distro designed to run a Java service?

Tags: java

Is there a 64-bit linux distro available that is made to run a Java JVM inside of it?   What I mean, is that it would be nice to have a simpler distribution of Linux that is small and fast to setup that is designed only to run a Java server.

I need to configure my 64-bit JVM with 2GB-3GB of max heap.

If not, any recommendations on which Linux server distro to use?   How is OpenSolaris?  Any benefit to using that?  The base memory footprint of OpenSolaris is 708MB.  Thats way too big.  It needs to be under 400MB for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several minimalist Linuxes where you can just install what you need. Ubuntu Server would probably be easiest to set up, but if all you want is Java, you could probably get Arch running like that pretty easily. Just do a base install and then:

```
pacman -Sy jdk jre
```

You could get it booting *real* fast and light since you wouldn't need any daemons running except network (and probably sshd).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any distro that is designed *just* to run a JVM -- it'd be a pretty niche thing.  Any distribution you're familiar with should be able to do the job.  I prefer Debian, myself, but it's more important to pick something you (or whoever will be managing the system day-to-day) is comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a linux distro that's designed to run *just* java JVM.

However, I've always found that Ubuntu is pretty fast to deploy java apps (especially Tomcat6) on, apt-get handles the majority of the configuration as well as all of the installation.

Just make sure you use sun-java6-bin, and not gcj, and it'll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago, I rolled my own Linux distro that included a bare kernel and the latest JVM with a few-liner init scripts.  It was fun to try and integrate JVM instantiation within init and kernel start, but had limited usage.

Are you rather looking for a distro that would be geared *specifically* for employing JVM instances?